# What is the difference between short adressing mode and long addressing mode

Tags: cpu-architecture, addressing-mode

While going through some data sheets of a processor architecture , i saw the terms, 
short addressing mode and long addressing mode

Can anybody give me the general idea of the terms(not needed to be processor specific!)

/renjith_g

Comment: Which processor architecture? Things like this are processor specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A short addressing mode uses a
  relative address, calculated as (some
  register + some smallish constant),
  which generally allows small/few/fast
  instructions, but can only address a small range of memory;
- A long addressing mode
  uses absolute addresses, which
  generally require large/many/slow
  instructions, but which can access any memory.

I'll give as an example ARM code, but this probably applies (in the general sense) to many other processors.

Each ARM instruction (ignoring Thumb) is 32 bits long, and for the sake of this example, we'll pretend the ARM can access a 32-bit address space.

Each instruction must be decoded, essentially by breaking down those 32 bits into various fields - and some of those bits must be used to store the type of the instruction.

Hopefully therefore, it should be clear that you can't load an arbitrary address into a register in one instruction:

```
MOV Rn, #AABBCCDD
```

Won't work - since we need to use bits to specify the instruction (MOV) and the destination register (Rn), we don't have 32 bits left to store a 32-bit address.

So, if we want the address of something in a register, we have a few options:

**1. Use PC-relative**

There's a pseudo-op which works as follows:

```
ADR Rn, .label
...
.label
```

Which gets expanded to:

```
ADD Rn, PC, (.label - here)
```

Provided .label is within about 4k of the current instruction, we can add/subtract from the current PC (program counter) to get that address. That's a relative address.

**2. Use multiple instructions**

You can build up an arbitray address using adds or ors:

```
MOV Rn, #AA000000
ADD Rn, Rn, #00BB0000
ADD Rn, Rn, #0000CC00
ADD Rn, Rn, #000000DD
```

(Actually you can do it much more efficiently, but you get the idea).

**3. Store the absolute address in a known relative location**

If you know the address you want is stored nearby, you can load it from memory:

```
ADR Rn, .store
LDR Rn, [Rn]

.store
EQU #AABBCCDD
```

Now, other processor architectures may have variable-length instructions (eg x86), so you can choose whether to use a short relative addressing mode (eg relative to PC or another register), or a longer (and probably) slower instruction which holds an entire 32-bit address.

Comment: I have got some idea.
But can you be little bit specific towards the above two addressing modes?





/renjith_g

Comment: @RenjithG the examples are very specific. Given you dont actually state the CPU the answer is perfect and cannot be improved. If your doing ASM you should be able to carry the example over to whatever CPU has your attention.